# What is going wrong in my code to generate pythagorean triplets?

Tags: java, math

I was using this code to solve Project Euler's Problem #9. Miraculously, it was able to generate the correct solution for me, but then I realized that there a huge problems in my code which I can't just sweep under the rug and move onto the next problem. I removed a few pieces of code that pertained to solving the problem and kept what is necessary to generate the pythagorean triplets. Prior to writing the code, I read this article on how to formulate the numbers: formula for generating pythagorean triples:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple

Here is my code:

```
public class Problem9 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        int c = 0;

        for (int m = 1; m < 6; m++) {
            for (int n = m + 1; n < 21; n++) {
                a = (int) (Math.pow(n, 2) - Math.pow(m, 2));
                b = 2 * n * m;
                c = (int) (Math.pow(n, 2) + Math.pow(m, 2));

                if ((Math.pow(a, 2) + Math.pow(b, 2)) == Math.pow(c, 2)) {
                    System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c);
                    // System.out.println(a*b*c);
                }
            }
        }
    } // end main
} // end class
```

The code starts off doing the right thing by printing `3,4,5` but, then it prints `8,6,10` which I know is a multiple of the prior triplet, but I don't understand why it prints it in the wrong order. It keeps doing this all the way to the limit that I set. How do I fix this? I would also appreciate a pointer as to how to prevent the multiples from being generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's only because of what the formulae for `a`, `b` and `c` are; there's nothing logically wrong with your code. If you want them to be output in order, just put a check in before your print statement.

```
if (a > b)
    System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c);
else
    System.out.println(b + " " + a + " " + c);
```

Comment: You're saying that I just need to put that control flow right after I check if a^2 + b^2 = c^2 ?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer: I mean that you'd need to replace your output statement with it.

Comment: Like this?

`if(Math.pow(a, 2) + Math.pow(b, 2) == Math.pow(c, 2)) {
     if (a > b){
      System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c);
     } else {
         System.out.println(b + " " + a + " " + c);
     }
    }
   } 
  }`

Comment: @Cherry_Developer: Eh? Why? You literally just need to replace `System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c);` with that control block.

Comment: I did do that. Then it nests your control block within the ` if ((Math.pow(a, 2) + Math.pow(b, 2)) == Math.pow(c, 2))` No? I'm sorry If I am misunderstanding what you are trying to say.

Comment: I figured it out. It should be `if (b > a){
      System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c);
     } else {
         System.out.println(b + " " + a + " " + c);`

Now it prints them in order

Answer (score 0):

If you go through your program with a debugger, it is pretty clear how it generates an output.  The first for loop starts at 1 and goes to 5, meaning that there will be 4 iterations. On iteration 1, The second for loop starts at 2 and goes to 20.  On iteration 2, the second for loop starts at 3 and goes to 20. Can you see how your for loops are searching the same space twice? It then checks every single combination for compliance with the general rule, "a squared plus b squared equals c squared".  This is a "brute force" approach, where you search every potential number for a condition.  Is there something about the condition, which can help you eliminate the potential numbers?  Is there some pattern in the existing numbers that can help you search for the pattern instead of testing the condition?

Comment: Isn't the pattern of the triplet just the condition that I implemented?